# Tensorflow: define placeholders/operation name in image pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to save my trained Tensorflow model, so it can be deployed by restoring the model file (I'm following [this](http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/) example, which seems to make sense). To do this, however, I need to have named tensors, so that I can do reload the variables with something like:

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
w1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("my_tensor:0")
```

I am queuing images from a list of filenames using *string_input_producer* (code below), but how do I name the tensors so that I can reload them at a later stage?

```
import tensorflow as tf

flags = tf.app.flags
conf = flags.FLAGS

class ImageDataSet(object):
  def __init__(self, img_list_path, num_epoch, batch_size):

    # Build the record list queue
    input_file = open(images_list_path, 'r')
    self.record_list = []
    for line in input_file:
      line = line.strip()
      self.record_list.append(line)
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(self.record_list, num_epochs=num_epoch)
    image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    _, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file, conf.img_colour_channels)

    # preprocess
    #  ...

    min_after_dequeue = 1000
    capacity = min_after_dequeue + 400 * batch_size
    self.images = tf.train.shuffle_batch(image, batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
      min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to restore the graph for testing or deploying.

For these purposes, you can edit your graph by insert a placeholder as an entrance of the testing data.

To edit the graph, you can use tf's [graph editor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.graph_editor), or build an new graph with placeholder and save it.

Comment: Yes - my intention is to restore the graph for deployment. It looks like I should create a placeholder for the *image* variable, and then use tf.assign to put data into it

Comment: Here is a simple example [insert_placeholder.py](https://github.com/Zehaos/MobileNet/blob/master/tools/insert_placeholder.py), and test it [test_forzen_graph](https://github.com/Zehaos/MobileNet/blob/master/tools/test_forzen_graph.py).